# Send UDP message to Android phone from JAVA server

Tags: java, android, udp, nat

I need to implement a messaging system for Android phones.
The server has static IP, it runs JAVA and it should send periodically UDP ping messages to android phones.
As I understand mobile phones have NAT IP.
The question is how server can send message to this IP.

Comment: Have you already tried to implement a server using any kind of networking API/library or how much research you have done so far?

Comment: Hi. I'll be glad to get information about some good library.

Comment: Netty seems a very promising choice for your use-case. They've got a strong community and plenty examples/tutorials to start with.